# widget WP in theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing my first wordpress theme and I have a doubt.

how to put a widget in theme directly, without sidebars (only code)?

```
class TVP_Check_Repairs extends WP_Widget { ... }
```

Comment: what's your question ? what you mean " how to put a widget in theme directly, without sidebars (only code)" explain in detail

Comment: for example, I put a shortcode directly to the subject, I have to do 
`<?php print do_shortcode('[nivoslider id = "61 "]'); ?>` I wanted to do the same for widgets. put widgets in the theme without sidebars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the_widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget)

```
the_widget($widget, $instance, $args);
```